# "What is your hobby?" VS "What are you into?"

Tags: expressions, expression-choice

My British English teacher told us that the expression "What is your hobby?" sounds childish so use "What are you into?" instead. Is it true? If so, why does that sound so?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm British, and "hobby" doesn't sound the least "childish" to me, though it is more formal than "what are you in to?".

Comment: @WS2 The word 'hobby' is fine, but I still think the question sounds a bit like an interrogation. Even 'what hobbies do you have?' is more natural. Mind you in a context where it's already being discussed it could be fine.

Comment: I am from the US (BosWash corridor) and hobby to me is something trivial.  But "what are you into" is so hippie.  These days "what keeps you sane?" seems like the right phrasing.

Comment: _What are you into?_ is very informal.  If you want something more natural (at least west coast US), you ask _Do you have any hobbies?_

Comment: @ab2 Would you have preferred "What are your extra-curricula interests?" That's probably what I would say. It is the type of irony, so beloved in Britain, which smooths the way with a mildly humorous note of exaggerated formality.

Comment: @WS2, "extra-curricular" means in addition to the curriculum. It's applicable to students, but not to workers.

Comment: That's the point about irony. Like referring to your lunch break as "feeding time".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You teacher has expressed a personal opinion, one I do not share. "What are you into?" is a slang expression from the 1980s. It's as out of date as the mullet haircut.

How about, "What do you like to do in your leisure time?"

Comment: I had to laugh at the mullet haircut comparison. It's a good analogy, but unfortunately not as out of date as I'd wish in some places. And perhaps that teacher is from such a place?

Comment: He's in his 40's and from Cambridge.

Comment: Out of date? I think it depends very much on context. It can be fine, and *what’s you hobby?* sounds even worse to my ears.

Answer (score 1):

"What is your hobby" is assuming that you have a recognised hobby; in fact it seems to insinuate that ever human has a hobby; like what is your blood-type or what is your date of birth? There's actually something about it that makes me think of filling out forms rather than small talk conversation. 
'What are you into?' is more general; it's assuming you must be interested in something.
You could of course first ask 'do you have any hobbies?' And then ask what the hobby is.

Comment: Agree wholeheartedly with this answer. *What are you into?* is very general, non-controversial and fairly friendly small talk intro.